# What to use as endpoint binding instead of wsHttpBinding (for Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I created a WCF service that has functions that return IEnumerable collections. I added it to Silverlight 4.0 as a service reference, but it doesn't like it.

What endpoint binding could I use instead that would work in this scenario? And, to change it, do I just change the web.config for my service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `basicHttpBinding`. Disclaimer: This used to be true in earlier versions of Silverlight, I hope it still is.

Answer (score 1):

There are posibility to use TCP bindings, but I am not sure if you can do it on web based application. But even web based applications have several options of HTTP bindings, say BASIC and as in your case WS HTTP bindings.

You always and easy can switch it to any bindings in config file, or in C# code if you are running as self host app. (without IIS)